# In what ways can I replenish "salt"?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

Salt is the essentially the "mana" portion of abilities in Bioshock: Infinite.  In what ways can I get more salt? Are there any ways besides looting corpses and boxes for vials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the other answers, [Elizabeth will occasionally give you Salts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcym7.jpg). More details behind that as mentioned in the answer(s) to this question: [How does Elizabeth getting various loot and then giving it to you work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112470/how-does-elizabeth-getting-various-loot-and-then-giving-it-to-you-work)

Also, from the BioShock wiki, "[Salts](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Salts)" article:

> ...certain beverages such as coffee and soda will also replenish a small portion of the player's Salts, while drinking alcohol will consume a small amount. Smoking cigarettes will also increase the player's Salts, though at a cost to their health.

Watch out for Salt Machines that will refill 100% of your Salts, free of charge and can be used repeatedly:

[image: Andrew Ryan's worst nightmare.]

Answer (score 3):

You can replenish your Salts (health and ammo as well) at Dollar Bill vending machines completely (100%) for $67 or partially (25%) for $19.

I recommend upgrading your Salt capacity to 10 before upgrading on your health or shields.

Be on the lookout for vest gear with "Blood to Salt", allows your enemies give Salts upon death 40% of the time.

Comment: *"I recommend upgrading your Salt capacity to 10 before upgrading on your health or shields"* - You clearly aren't playing on 1999 mode...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I'm not cool enough to be that hardcore. D:

Answer (score 1):

There are vending machines which sell salt.  And keep your eye out for salt dispensing machines, like you find during the carnival section of the first level.

Answer (score -2):

most of the time you just find salt and extra vigor and plasmid bottles laying around that come in handy throughout the game. You just have to keep your eyes peeled.